# Set dialogMessage in preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am using preference.xml. Since my app uses Google Maps API, I need to show Legal Notices as a part of my about screen. I have successfully created activity that extends DialogPreference and the dialog is shown when clicked. But the dialogMessage needs to be a string as below

```
String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
    getApplicationContext());
```

So how can I show this string in android:dialogMessage?

Here is OptionDialogPreference.java

```
public class OptionDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

public OptionDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

Comment: [android:dialogMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#attr_android:dialogMessage)

Comment: But how can I set the textview?

Comment: Does your dialog inflate your own view?

Comment: Currently my dialog just contains a empty constructor.

Comment: Should I use this -TextView msgTxt = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message); inside a onCreate? And then say msgTxt.setText(LicenseInfo).

Comment: I need some more code.

Comment: I got an idea; one moment :)

Comment: Sure thanks for reply. Take your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class OptionDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    private Context _context;

    public OptionDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogMessage(GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(context));
    }    
 }
```

Comment: So I need to create a layout with textview?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check and get back soon.

Comment: it is saying that method getApplicationContext is undefined

Comment: I had a sneaking feeling it would. I have changed the code again. notice the context changes.

Comment: After clicking the dialog preference

Comment: There is a setDialogMessage. Can we use that?